# visual studio error,The Mac could not be activated because of the following error: ActivationError

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios

Iam trying to connect to my mac from visual studio installed in windows system, It shows the following error,

"The Mac could not be activated because of the following error: ActivationError"

i had recently upgraded my mac, before that I was able to connect visual studio with mac,Can anyone please help me.